# Recursion : method which takes a string, and for each repeating sequence of characters in the string, removes all but one of them

Tags: recursion

Complete the following method which takes a string, and for each repeating sequence of characters in the string, removes all but one of them. For example, given the input string "AAAABCCDDDDAACCCCCC", the method should return "ABCDAC".

YOUR CODE MUST BE RECURSIVE. Do not use any loops (while, do/while, or for). Do not declare any variables outside of the method. You may declare local variables inside the method.

```
public static String eliminateRepeats (String s)
{
```

Comment: @Tudor his "public static String eliminateRepeats(String s)" is java.

Comment: @JonathanPayne: Could also be C#, but Java is slightly more likely, based on the capitalisation of the types and the method name.

Comment: Not a very good assignment, as this actually requires a loop. So, you are learning how to fake a loop using recursion, instead of learning how to use recursion properly.

Comment: @Guffa: Loops are just a poor attempt to fake recursion.

Comment: @userunknown: Hehe... But seriously, in this case a proper loop would be a much better implementation. It would create a lot less intermediate objects, be a lot faster, and it could handle huge strings as it would not be limited by stack space.

Comment: @Guffa: Why do you think so? What is the case here? Runtime performance? Memory saving? Teaching something? What? Recursion, maybe?

Comment: @userunknown: For any practical use of such a method, a loop would be better. To learn recursion this assigment isn't very good, as recursion would not be the logical choise for a solution.

Comment: @Guffa: That's your personal opinion. In functional languages I use recursive methods all the time. It avoids the use of changing variables, which are side effects - an unwanted feature. The compiler can eliminate the recursion if it is in tail position.

Comment: @userunknown: This is not an assignment in a functional language.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Recurse
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        System.out.println( recurse( "AAAABCCDDDDAACCCCCC" ) );
    }

    private static String recurse( String s )
    {
        if ( s == null || s.equalsIgnoreCase("") )
        {
            return "";
        }
        else if ( s.length() > 1 )
        {
            if ( !s.substring( 0 , 1 ).equalsIgnoreCase( s.substring( 1 , 2 ) ) )
            {
                return s.substring( 0 , 1 ) + recurse( s.substring( 1 ) );
            }

            return recurse( s.substring( 1 ) );
        }
        else
        {
            return s.substring( 0 , 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work, however you are using the output buffer as a global variable instead of returning the result, so it would not meet the requirements of the assignment.

Comment: I don't understand why people so often offer 'ignoreCase', without being asked for.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that you *need* a loop to solve this, so you just fake a loop by calling the method recursively with smaller and smaller parts of the string.

There is no way to divide the work into smaller parts, as one usually does when using recursion (like for example split the string in half). You just have to process one character at a time, and call the method with the rest of the string.

Example in C#:

```
public static string EliminateRepeats(string s) {
  return
    s.Length == 1 ?
      s
    :
      (s[0] != s[1] ? s.Substring(0, 1) : "")
      + EliminateRepeats(s.Substring(1));
}
```

(Code inspired by Jonathan Paynes code.)

Comment: @userunknown: That's easily fixed if that is required. Change `== 1` to `< 2`.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong with the answer, it can't improve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// use a default value for the lastchar for the first char, 
// which is impossible to meet in an regular string
def concentrate (s: String, lastchar: Char = 0) : String = {
    // recursive methods always need to know when it is enough
    if (s.length == 0) s else 
    if (s(0) == lastchar) concentrate (s.substring (1), lastchar) else 
    s(0) +  concentrate (s.substring (1), s(0)) }

concentrate ("AAAABCCDDDDAACCCCCC")
```

Here is a tailrecursive variation:

```
@tailrec 
def concentrate (s: String, carry:String = "", lastchar: Char = 0) : String = {
    if (s.length == 0) carry else 
    if (s(0) == lastchar) concentrate (s.substring (1), carry, lastchar) else 
    concentrate (s.substring (1), carry + s(0), s(0)) }
```

It has the recursive call in the last position, since the resulting string gets glued together on the fly, and passed as parameter. In Scala, this can be optimized by the compiler to run nearly as fast as a loop with mutable variables, and it will not blow the stack - not even for very long Strings.